# How to tell find_package() which version (debug, release) of lib should find

Tags: c++, qt, cmake

When I try to find a Qt library I use [find_package()](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_package.html) command. But here is a problem. This command imports two versions of the same library. 
By version I mean **debug** and **realease**. For example:

*libQt5Core_debug.5.dylib*

*libQt5Core.5.11.0.dylib*

Because of this unwanted behaviour I get runtime linking linking error.

```
objc[15947]: Class QMacAutoReleasePoolTracker is implemented in both /usr/local/Qt-5.11.0/lib/libQt5Core_debug.5.dylib (0x104326d40) and /usr/local/Qt-5.11.0/lib/libQt5Core.5.11.0.dylib (0x1075c41c8). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[15947]: Class QT_ROOT_LEVEL_POOL__THESE_OBJECTS_WILL_BE_RELEASED_WHEN_QAPP_GOES_OUT_OF_SCOPE is implemented in both /usr/local/Qt-5.11.0/lib/libQt5Core_debug.5.dylib (0x104326db8) and /usr/local/Qt-5.11.0/lib/libQt5Core.5.11.0.dylib (0x1075c4240). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[15947]: Class RunLoopModeTracker is implemented in both /usr/local/Qt-5.11.0/lib/libQt5Core_debug.5.dylib (0x104326de0) and /usr/local/Qt-5.11.0/lib/libQt5Core.5.11.0.dylib (0x1075c4268). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
QObject::moveToThread: Current thread (0x7fcee5f02c20) is not the object's thread (0x7fcee5c04c10).
Cannot move to target thread (0x7fcee5f02c20)

You might be loading two sets of Qt binaries into the same process. Check that all plugins are compiled against the right Qt binaries. Export DYLD_PRINT_LIBRARIES=1 and check that only one set of binaries are being loaded.
```

My CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(Server)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE "Debug")
set (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS " -lprotobuf")
add_definitions(-DDEBUG_MODE)

set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)

include_directories(/usr/local/boost_1_67_0/)

find_package(Qt5Widgets  REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt5Core REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt5Sql REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt5Network REQUIRED)


set(SRCS  Server.cpp Request_Response.pb.cc)


add_executable(Server main.cpp ${SRCS})


target_link_libraries(Server Qt5::Core Qt5::Widgets Qt5::Sql Qt5::Network)
```

**Question**:
How can I tell cmake not to link my target with more than one version of the same library?

OS: macOS High Sierra 10.13.4

cmake: 3.11.0

EDIT:
Someone said it's duplicate of [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32780161/find-package-for-both-debug-and-release-with-visual-studio) and of course
it concerns debug and release installation with find_package(), but this is not the same. In his case debug and release versions of a lib were allocated in different paths.

In my case I have got those 2 versions of the same library in one folder. */usr/local/Qt-5.11.0/lib*

Look at this:

```
$:lib artur$ ls | grep -i qt5core
libQt5Core.5.11.0.dylib
libQt5Core.5.11.dylib
libQt5Core.5.dylib
libQt5Core.dylib
libQt5Core.la
libQt5Core.prl
libQt5Core_debug.5.11.0.dylib
libQt5Core_debug.5.11.dylib
libQt5Core_debug.5.dylib
libQt5Core_debug.dylib
libQt5Core_debug.la
libQt5Core_debug.prl
```

Note:
Everything works fine if I change build type.

from
`set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE "Debug")`

to

`set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE "Release")`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [find\_package for both debug and release with Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32780161/find-package-for-both-debug-and-release-with-visual-studio)

Comment: @MohammadKanan This issue has similarities like debug, release install. But it doesn't address my problem.

Comment: Fixed: I uninstalled manual installed Qt and used Homebrew to install qt5 and it worked. :)

Comment: You can also find Qt5 following what has been dubbed as [finding Qt5 the right way](https://blog.kitware.com/cmake-finding-qt5-the-right-way/).

Comment: @MohammadKanan The question is about a Linux build. The one you linked is about Visual Studio (Windows). [VS works differently](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/guide/tutorial/Packaging%20Debug%20and%20Release.html). Don't throw around the "duplicate" mark so quickly. It's one of the worst parts of the SO experience for people asking questions when it doesn't even apply.